# Answerer comments out of line?

Tags: discussion

The original author of [This Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/359285/57332) has made some comments that are, in my opinion, out of line. I'm not sure if I'd be the best person to call him out on it, considering it was my question to begin with. He's being rude, disrespectful, and he's cursing.

I will admit that I don't know everything there is to know about the subject I asked about. That's the very reason I asked. I'm here to engage in a professional manner and to, learn, or help someone else learn something useful out of the little bit of knowledge I can offer to the field of server administration.

I think that civility, respect, and helpful answers are more valuable than answers (and comments) which make assumptions that the "questioner" hasn't provided more information than he thinks he should provide, or that the questioner has knowingly provided useless information.

Thanks goes to Iain who edited the answer shortly after it was posted... I didn't even see the original answer until it had been edited, so went through the history of it.

Comment: I'm not going through all his old answers, it seems to me this isn't the first time he's outdone TomTom.

Comment: Whether it's your question or not, feel free to flag what you think is offensive or inappropriate. I'm sure the mods will make a decision impartially.

Comment: Yeah, I flagged one of the comments. I'll have to say though, his answer (and comments) got me looking into some things, and I'm now in the process of adding PTR records for all of the domains hosted on this machine. You never know when you're going to learn something valuable!

Comment: @David, *everyone* knows something someone else doesn't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those are out of line. Rather stronger language than we like to see around here.

Comment: Can't say I was "offended", but it bothered me none-the-less on this type of site. Its the principle of the matter that bothered me more than anything. At any rate, I've accepted his answer as it did point me in the right direction. Anyway, thanks - aside from flagging, didn't know if it would be helpful to post about it in here or not. So I did (obviously).